# How to search for child nodes in xml using DOM Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I have the following XML structure

```
<CodeSnippet>
<Code id="code1">
<Tags>button java</Tags>
<Snippet>sample code</Snippet>
</Code>
<Code id="code2">
<Tags>eclipse jbutton java</Tags>
<Snippet>sample code</Snippet>
</Code>
<.....>
</CodeSnippet>
```

Now, I want to retrieve all the Snippet from the above xml when i search using Tags. For instance, if search for "java" then all the nodes that contain tags as "java" must return the snippet.

My search query is:

`//Code/Tags[contains(concat(' ',/text(),' '), ' "+ searchTags[0] +" ')]";`

Here, searchTags[0] contains "java".

My result set should contain the Snippets of the selected nodes i.e. code1 and code2 from above xml structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression:

```xml
//Code/Tags[contains(., 'Java')]/../Snippet
```

Comment: @dfsq...please see my question again. i have corrected it.

Comment: The answer still apply. Above XPath will retrieve `Snippet` nodes `Tags` contains "Java".

Comment: @dfsq..Yes, i am able to retrieve the "Tags" with your expression but i am unable to retrieve "Snippet". I am just executing your expression without changing.

Comment: Strange. What if you try `//Code/Tags[contains(./text(), 'Java')]/parent::Code/Snippet`?

Comment: i am able to retrieve "Tags" if i write like //Code/Tags/text()[contains(., 'Java')]. For getting "Snippet" i tried like //Code/Tags/text()[contains(., 'Java')]/../Snippet/text(). But didn't work out.

Comment: What is the result for `//Code/Tags/text()[contains(./text(), 'Java')]/../Snippet`?

Comment: Don't use all those `text()` selectors, simply select the element nodes: `//Code[Tags[contains(., 'Java')]]/Snippet`. If you select `text()` nodes then you have to go up two levels e.g. `//Code/Tags/text()[contains(., 'Java')]/../../Snippet`.

Comment: @dfsq.. //Code/Tags/text()[contains(./text(), 'Java')]/../Snippet doesn't return anything. if i remove the "/../" then use //Code/Tags/text()[contains(./text(), 'Java')]/Snippet it is working

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving all the "Tags" containing "java", I used the below xpath expression,

//Code/Tags/text()[contains(., 'java')]

For retrieving all the "Snippet" related to the tags "java", I used below expression

//Code/Tags[contains(./text(), 'java')]/parent::Code/Snippet/text()

Thanks to @dfsq for helping me out with his expression. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can write :

```
//Tags//Snippet
```

If you used XPath

Comment: I have posted my answer with what context i was looking for. Please have a look. Your right if i do not want any search using tag but just get snippet only.